# HTML Email Templates delivered Incompletely in Lightning List Email

Tags: lightning, controller, email-template, lightning-design-system

I have few html email templates which are used to send mass emails to Contact and Campaigns. 
They are working fine in Salesforce classic whereas in Lightning, they are delivered incompletely. We need to send this template completely as there are few links on the template where recipients can subscribe. I didnt find any article online supporting this issue. Is there any workaround or can anyone suggest how to send template completely in Mass email in Lightning.
[image: While selecting the template]
[image: While sending the email]

Comment: Are you using the email message object in your Lightning Org? I also see your question has the Visualforce-Template tag on it. Are your email templates visualforce templates or are they classic email templates? It makes a huge difference. There's a great deal of documentation on this in the Salesforce Help.

Comment: Yes @cmprogdev. HTML templates are working completely in email message lightning object. Whereas, when I send list emails from Campaign or Contact, it is sending incompelete template. The html templates that I use are from Classic. Visualforce-template tag in my question came by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarification the problem only exists with list emails on Campaign and Contact, I think I found the answer to your question as to why you're having the problem you're seeing. List emails in Lightning are limited to 32,000 characters.

See [List Email Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limitations_email_list_email.htm&type=5) and [Considerations for Sending List Email in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_list_email_considerations.htm&type=5).

Comment: Awesome @crmprogdev. I was trying to find suitable document to verify this issue. Thank you very much for the info !